# Launch multiple Chrome Browser simultaneously using two testNG.XML Files

Tags: xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I am planning to launch Chrome browsers simultaneously for two testng.xml files. Each testng.xml file has more than two tests.

Then, I have combined two xml files in single suite file named as **parentsuite.xml** file.

Two chrome browsers gets launched when testng1.xml and testng2.xml files have only test method each. But If the testng1.xml file has more than 1 test means, second chrome browser gets launched only after testng1.xml file execution gets completed.

Please find the below example.

**testng1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Parallel suite 1" >
 <test name="Browser Setup">
  <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
   <classes>    
    <class name="com.simpletest.LaunchBrowser"/>
   </classes> 
 </test> 

  <test name="ApplicationSignin">
   <paramater name = "username" value="xxxx"/>
   <parameter name="pwd" value="1111"/>
   <classes>    
    <class name="com.simpletest.Signin"/>
   </classes> 
  </test> 
</suite>
```

**testng2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Parallel suite 2" >
   <test name="Browser Setup">
     <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
       <classes>    
        <class name="com.simpletest.LaunchBrowser"/>
       </classes> 
   </test> 

   <test name="Application Signin">
    <paramater name = "username" value="yyyy"/>
    <parameter name="pwd" value="2222"/>
     <classes>    
      <class name="com.simpletest.Signin"/>
    </classes> 
  </test> 
</suite>
```

**Sample Code for Launching Browser**

```
public class LaunchBrowser
{
  @Test
  @Parameters("browser")
  public void startBrowser(String browser)
  {
    switch(browser)
    {
     case "Chrome":

        desCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        desCapabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
        desCapabilities.setBrowserName(DriverConstants.CHROME_BROWSER);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        System.out.println("For Browser : " + browser);
        break;

    case "Firefox":
        desCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        desCapabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
        desCapabilities.setBrowserName(DriverConstants.FIREFOX_BROWSER);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        System.out.println("For Browser : " + browser);
        break;

    default :
        System.out.println("Brower choice not available");     

    }
}
```

**parentsuite.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Selenium Test Suite" thread-count="2" preserve-order="true">
  <suite-files> 
    <suite-file path="testng1.xml" />
    <suite-file path="testng2.xml" />
  </suite-files> 
</suite>
```

**Note:** How to fix this issue without using Grid concept. Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Comment: may be because of missing parameter named browser in the second test. please add browser parameter to the second test  try again.

Comment: Please show us the browser instantiation code snippet. Am guessing that the problem lies in that part only.

Comment: In first test method, browser should be launched and in second test method, I need to perform some other action, Eg : navigate to stackoverflow.com. So no need to open the browser again.

Comment: @MohanKumar - Your browser instantiation code is within an `@Test` method. So I am not quite sure as to what are you trying to do. Can you please help add more context to your code ? It would be good if you can please help add the complete code snippet for your two classes (you can remove out all the complexities and just trim it down to instantiation of webdriver and loading a url)

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - I have updated the code, please let us know if there are any other concern.

Comment: @MohanKumar - What does `com.simpletest.Signin` look like ?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - In this class I have a code for which URL to hit and then user credentials for signin purpose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153222/discussion-between-mohan-kumar-and-krishnan-mahadevan).

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to spin off your `@Test` methods in parallel, you would need to set the attribute `parallel` to one of the below values in the `<suite>` tag

- `methods` - This would cause all the `@Test` methods to run in parallel.
- `tests` - This would cause `<test>` tags to be run in parallel, but the `@Test` methods that are present in each of the `<test>` tags would be run in sequence.
- `classes` - This would cause TestNG to run all the test classes in parallel (test class is essentially a class that houses one or more `@Test` method), but still the `@Test` methods are run in sequence.
- `instances` - This is involved only when there's a `@Factory` annotated constructor.

So you can choose one of the parallel execution strategies as per your need to have TestNG to run your tests in parallel.

But all said and done, going by what you explained to me in the comments, your test code needs a bit of fixes. You haven't shown how you are sharing the `WebDriver` instances between two or more of your `@Test` methods in your test classes.

So there are chances that once you enable parallel execution, you will see new problems.

TestNG by default (when run via maven surefire plugin for e.g.,) doesn't run multiple suites in parallel. In order to learn how to run multiple suites (`<suite>`) in parallel, please refer to my blog post [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/parallel-execution-of-multiple-testng-suites/)